# How are instances of class objects used to build applications?

Tags: class, oop, object

I'm currently working on an assignment about OOP and I'm a bit stuck on figuring out some examples of how class objects are used to build applications. I'm assuming it means things such as buttons, labels and that type of thing?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Everyone here could wave their hands on the topic. I'd recommend you try building a simple tic-tac-toe game in java/python and you'll have all the answers you need. Even better, you will introduce yourself to software architecture which is a big challenge at any level of programming.

Comment: You can also treat yourself with this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odjdWym0t4I&t= and then watch the next one called "under the hood"